# Sweep a log-dnorm across a training set matrix to find log-likelihood

Tags: r, machine-learning, naivebayes, log-likelihood

As part of a machine learning class assignment, I am implementing a NaiveBayes classifier without using any external library.

My training data set X has 8 features and one binary label for 800 rows; I have calculated 1:8 vectors for mean and sd for each feature by class, along with the priors for the two classes.

In order to assess accuracy of the classifier on the training dataset, I want to generate a matrix Y with the same dimensions (i=800, j=8) in which each element y_ij is given as

```
y_ij = dnorm(x_ij, mean = mean_j, sd_j, log = T)
```

I have tried sweep, apply, and lapply without success. I am stuck and unfortunately this is an issue with familiarity with R rather than understanding the algo. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `dnorm(x_ij, ...` is the `x_ij` the original value? And you want a new 800x8 matrix `Y` with new values `y_ij = dnorm(x_ij, ...`?

Comment: Yes to both your questions.

Comment: I have low reputation so my vote doesn't count, but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: np. you can probably accept the answer in lieu of an upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better data setup for this, but if you already have `X` and two vectors of means and sds, `xmean` and `xsd`, you can use `sapply`. Here's a reproducible example:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 3)
xmean <- apply(X, 2, mean)
xsd <- apply(X, 2, sd)
sapply(1:ncol(X), function(j) { dnorm(X[,j], xmean[j], xsd[j], log = TRUE) })
```